# R scatterplot3d with error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

When running the codes as below, I got the `margins too large error`.

```
x <- seq(min(lats),max(lats),length.out=100)
y <- seq(min(lons),max(lons),length.out=100)
xy <- merge(x,y)
colnames(xy) <- c('lat','lon')
z <- predict(fit,xy)
scatterplot3d(x=xy$lat,y=xy$lon,z=z,xlim=c(min(lats),max(lats)),ylim=c(min(lons),max(lons)) )
```

I am very sure, x,y,z are all correct.

Even trying with the sample code on the help doc of scatterplot3d, I still got the error:

```
  ## example 1
  z <- seq(-10, 10, 0.01)
  x <- cos(z)
  y <- sin(z)
  scatterplot3d(x, y, z, highlight.3d=TRUE, col.axis="blue",
      col.grid="lightblue", main="scatterplot3d - 1", pch=20)
```

I checked with other questions it seems like this error happens with plot, ggplot, etc. But most people are talking about specific solutions, some suggest change from RStudio to console can solve it. However, generally what this error means when I try to plot something? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: The second example runs without error for me and displays the expected spiral. You need to offer the details about your machine and R's graphics devices. Try `dev.off()` to shut down the open screen device and then `dev.new()` to create another.

Comment: @DWin I tried all ways to clean the memory or something like that, dev.off() included, but that does not help. I tried even very small set of data like only 10*10 points, but still get that error. I feel it is like something is not compatible with the environment.

Comment: Well, I decided to switch to rgl and that works well.